# ExtJs 4.2 Themes

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

We are working with Sechnca's extjs
On the recent version 4.2 - they release the option to build a theme and compile it using their own CMD.

We are looking for a method to create a new theme but instead of using Sechnca CMD use Compass.

Has anyone been successful in doing that?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, "no".

I was using compass with extjs 4.1. While you might be successful in trying to do it with 4.2, I spent about 2 days trying to get it to work. Eventually I gave up and started to use the `sencha` command line utility. I would really suggest sticking with the methods they outline in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/theming). The `sencha` command does a lot of the heavy lifting for you, error checking, validation, it even slices up the CSS3 gradients into images for you.